# Streams - anyMatch in filter produces IllegalStateException

Tags: java, java-stream

I am trying to iterate through two lists and I am getting an `IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed`

```
file().forEach(line -> {
    boolean match = ordersSupplier.get().anyMatch(order -> order == line.id);
    if (match) {
        //do something;
    }
});
```

I know that anyMatch is a terminal operation, thats why I am getting this error. Can I parameterize a Supplier für anyMatch with the id of the line? Any Idea?

Comment: assuming `ordersSupplier` is `Optional<Stream>` and the error messages means that stream is already consumed, can you show more code ?

Comment: orderSupplier is Supplier<Stream<Integer>> should be Optional<Stream>?

Comment: show more code @user9923760 that stream should be consumed some where in the code

Comment: Put the orders in a set once, before this code: `Set<Integer> orders = ordersSupplier.get().collect(toSet());`. Then just use `if (orders.contains(line.id))` inside the `forEach`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collect the order ids in a `Set` and `filter` your line with the Stream API. Then you can execute your code in a `forEach`.

```
Set<String> orderIds = ordersSupplier.get().collect(toSet());

file().stream()
      .filter(l -> orderIds.contains(l.id))
      .forEach(
           line -> {
                    //do something;
       });
```